# How to create a boot application for windows 8 pro tablet?

Tags: windows-8, tablet, boot

I am having a tablet running on Windows 8 pro.
I need to create an application that is expected to run when the tablet boots.
Other applications should not be visible to the user.
Is this feasible?
If so please guide me on setting the boot up preference.

Answer (score 2):

There is a big chance that in windows 8.1 a [kiosk-mode](http://www.theverge.com/2013/4/20/4246818/windows-8-1-kiosk-mode-build-9374) will be introduced. You can then develop Modern-UI apps(aka Metro-Apps) that directly start after boot up. Windows 8.1 was announced on 26.6. Leaked road maps say it will be rolled out in august.

The kiosk-mode is called **Assigned Access** and you can set it up in the preference:
[image]

Sadly I wasn't able to find the function in my Windows 8.1 pro preview version. Hopefully it will make it into the final version of windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

I don't have full information about this but you can add your app to an start-up folder so that whenever your tablet boots,your application will start just like Google talk and other apps which starts at at he startup.